# How to set canonical tag in Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, meta-tags, next.js13

How do I set a canonical tag in Nextjs 13?

I used to use the `<head>` tag, but now it seems deprecated and the `generateMetadata` has no information about the canonical meta tag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I figured out a way:

```
export async function generateMetadata({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}) {
  const { slug} = params;
  const siteURL = 'https://example.com';

  return {
    title: `Your title`,
    description: `Your meta description`,
    alternates: {
      canonical: `${siteURL}/yourSlug/${slug}`,
    },
  };
}
```

Edit:
Check the comments if you don't want to provide the absolute path for the canonical URL.

Comment: If you've provided `metadataBase` in your root layout, then you do not need to provide absolute path for the `canonical` URL. Next.js will generate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default tags in the `layout.tsx` file in the `app` directory. Then use the [metaDataBase](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadatabase) to create a `base url`. Then with the `alternates` property you should be able to create canonical URLs for different routes of your website.

```
 alternates: {
    canonical: "/",
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.website.com/" />
</Head>
```

Comment: This method is not preferred in nextjs 13 use generateMetadata or simply define an static metadata object